# WordPress Notice "Undefined Index"

Tags: wordpress

I am getting following notice in WordPress

> Notice: Undefined index: _wpnonce in /var/www/vhosts/abc.biz/php/func.php on line 338

Any solution?
Thanks for help

Comment: what is the code on 338 line and can you post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, have to use isset() to check _wpnonce value, before comparing it.

```
if ( isset($_POST['_wpnonce']) && $_POST['_wpnonce'] = '123456789' ) {}
```

Thanks.

Comment: but, It doesn't affect the intentions of the use of wp_verify_nonce ?